# Show list of terms if empty or not

Tags: wordpress

I am wanting to get a list of taxomnies by the slug called teamembers_rank but I am at a loss

```
<?  
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'teammembersrank' );
if ($terms) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
      echo $term->name;
    } 
}
```

But its not printing out the list of terms I want it to show the list if empty or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your taxonomy slug is correct one: teammembersrank or teamembers_rank. Make sure your code within post loop. Use the following code with correct taxonomy slug.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'teammembersrank' );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
     ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $term->name;?> </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    endif;  
  ?>
```